# How to prove $(A_1 \times A_2) \cup (A_3 \times A_4)\subset ( A_1 \cup A_3 )\times ( A_2 \cup A_4)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Need your help to prove it any suggestions or any kind of answer will be appreciated.

$$(A_1 \times A_2) \cup (A_3 \times A_4)\subset ( A_1 \cup A_3 )\times ( A_2 \cup A_4)$$

Comment: consider any element on the LHS and demonstrate it is an element of the RHS

Comment: I've edited your question to use MathJax, our maths renderer. Check the source (by clicking [edit]) to see how it works. For further information about writing maths at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latexhelp/notation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling the LHS $S_1$ and the RHS $S_2$, if $x$ is an element of $S_1$ then it is either:

$$(a_1,a_2)$$

With $a_1\in A_1$ and $a_2\in A_2$ or it is:

$$(a_3,a_4)$$

With $a_3\in A_3$ and $a_4\in A_4$.

From here, can you prove this must be contained (it's pretty elementary) in the RHS $S_2$?

Answer (score 3):

First thing, be comfortable with all the notations. Be clear on what it means $X\cup Y$ and what it means $U\times V$, when does an element belong to each of these "things". Then be clear on what it means $K\subseteq L$. This includes understanding what is an ordered pair, and what does $x\in X$ really mean.

Now we can prove the statement. Simply show that the definition for $\subseteq$ holds, that is take an element from the left hand side, and using the definitions of all the symbols show that it is also an element of the right hand side. Draw a little square $\square$ or write $\rm Q.E.D$ to denote that the proof is complete.